# Updating Column of a table based on columns of a table on a different server

Tags: sql-server-2017

I'm trying to update a column of a table in one server based on the columns of a table in another server. This code works fine in the same database and server. I want Column1 of the table I'm updating to equal that of the other table WHERE the Column5 of first table and server matches that of Column5 of the other table on the other server.

I have created a Local Server Group and run this while connected to both. What else am I missing?

```
UPDATE [db1].[schema1].[table1] 
SET [server1].[db1].[schema1].[table1].[Column1] = [server2].[db1].[schema1].[table1].[Column1]
FROM [server1].[db1].[schema1].[table1], [server2].[db1].[schema1].[table1]WHERE [server1].[db1].[schema1].[table1].[Column5] = [server2].[db1].[schema1].[table1].[Column5]
```

Here's the error:

With a " exec sp_testlinkedserver server2" this is the result:

server2(userlogin): Msg 7411, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_testlinkedserver, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
Server 'server2' is not configured for DATA ACCESS.

With a "exec sp_serveroption 'server2', 'data access', 'true' " this is the result:

Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_serveroption, Line 27 [Batch Start Line 0]
User does not have permission to perform this action.

Looks to be a permission issue i'll need to reach out about. If I can't get those permissions. Is there a next best option ?

Comment: select name from sys.servers ---- both servers show up EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'server name' --- I don't have permissions. So if it's a permission thing is there a way to still do it?

Comment: You don't have permissions to add a new linked server, but it doesn't mean that you don't have them to access the existing ones... what value you get with  select is_data_access_enabled from sys.servers where name = 'server2'??

Comment: Try  exec sp_testlinkedserver Server2; what you get? If the test is unsuccessful it will raise an exception with the reason of the failure. If you get an error post it directly to the question, not in a comment

Comment: Do you have permissions to run this? exec sp_serveroption 'server2', 'data access', 'true'

Comment: Nope, no permissions yet. Tried "exec sp_serveroption 'server2', 'data access', 'true' " - Seems that would be my issue, right?

Comment: Is not a permissions issue, is configuration, ask sys admin to run this statement and you will be able to access the linked server without modifying your current permissions

Comment: Will reach out to them. Thanks. I'll update you when I know more

Comment: If you have permissions to connect direct to Server2 without the linked server you can use ad-hoc connections (openrowset, opendatasource)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get sysadmin privileges to use a LinkedServer, you only need to ask the sysadmin to execute the statement

```
exec sp_serveroption 'server2', 'data access', 'true'
```

It is not possible neither but you have the credentials to connect to server2, you can create an adhoc connection using `openrowset`

> OPENROWSET permissions are determined by the permissions of the user
>   name that is being passed to the OLE DB provider

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.[Column1] = T2.[Column1]
FROM [server1].[db1].[schema1].[table1] T1
JOIN OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', '<Connection string to Server2>',  
     'SELECT * FROM [db1].[schema1].[table1]') AS T2 ON T1.[Column5] = T2.[Column5]
```

Or `OpenDataSource`

> Any user can execute OPENDATASOURCE. The permissions that are used to
>   connect to the remote server are determined from the connection string

```
UPDATE T1
    SET T1.[Column1] = T2.[Column1]
    FROM [server1].[db1].[schema1].[table1] T1
    JOIN OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI', '<Connection string to Server2>').[db1].[schema1].[table1] AS T2 ON T1.[Column5] = T2.[Column5]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Still get this message. "SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server" All roads pointing to the admins if I want to be able to do this.

Comment: It also needs sa’s action :( is another server option, you will need to reach them anyway